# How to set focus on form with more of one button?

Tags: html, forms, button, focus

I have two buttons for the same form. In the HTML code I declared first the "Button One" and after the "Button Two".

When I display the form, the focus is on the "Button One", but I would like to have it on the other one without change them the screen position.

What I can do?

Comment: using jQuery $('#btnId').focus()

Comment: using angular and Angular-Material design, you need to use **md-autofocus**. There is a very good explanation here : https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.4/api/directive/mdAutofocus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Button Two").focus();
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify, by "#Button Two" I meant the button element's ID. `focus()` can also be used to focus on text input etc.

Answer (score 1):

Set `tabindex` to the second button less than the first one.

**EDIT**

yes, you can use javascript, `document.getElementById("button2").focus();`. Make sure you add this code on page load.

Comment: I tried that but it does not work. Maybe I have to use some JavaScript... so, it will work with all browsers?